# Why the page direct to index page of //localhost after click?

Tags: php, codeigniter, chat

I am building a chatbox learning from youtube, I followed the steps, but why my page goes to //localhost instead of alert something on current page?

Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Demu2OfTqI

JS Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("we made it");  //this alert works

    $("#submint_message").click(function(){
        alert("we made it");
        alert($("#chat_message").val());
    });
});
```

HTML Page:

```html
 <h1>Let's chat</h1>
    <div id="chat_viewport"></div>

    <div id="chat_input">
        <input id="chat_message" name="chat_message" type="text" value="" tabindex="1">
        <?php $this->load->helper('url');
         echo anchor('#','say it', array('title'=>'send this message','id'=>'submit_message'));?>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
```

After click "say it", the current page should alert the message I typed in.
But it actually goes to index page of my localhost.
[current chat page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgmvj.jpg)

[after click "say it"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB2eb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your element name. You attach event to `submint_message` instead of  `submit_message`. Also prevent the default behavior of anchor tag by adding `event.preventDefault();` 
Try below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("we made it");  //this alert works

    $("#submit_message").click(function(event){ // event parameter passed 
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior 
        alert("we made it");
        alert($("#chat_message").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank, I correct the typo, my javaScript line works, but after execution, it still goes to  //localhost

Comment: @Renee Updated the answer. Please try now.